# CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin error only in Safari

Tags: javascript, ajax, safari, axios

I've seen a couple similar issues but I can't find any meaningful response.

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://(URL).com/ajax-plan-array',
    config: {
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        }
    }
}).then(response => {
```

This extremely simple AJAX request is consistently blocked by Safari, but works fine in Chrome/Firefox etc etc. It keeps saying `https://(OTHERURL).com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

I've checked the headers provided by the server again and again and they're completely fine:

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: *
access-control-allow-methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, MKCOL, COPY, MOVE, LOCK
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-origin-list: *
```

Again, no other browser blocks this, just Safari. I am not sure how to debug this, as it gives no other information. What am I missing here?

Comment: Why are you adding an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the request?!

Comment: I don't know, it was a last-ditch attempt to fix it as I'd seen others try the same. Obviously didn't work ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.